# How to track activity for a do-not-reply email in the SendGrid account

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

We are new in Sendgrid and we want to use it to track our system email but it did not seems to work with the new API key. The system are using do-not-reply email to track on the user activity.Can I know how can we authenticate this email to keep track on the activity in the SendGrid?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. What system are you talking about?  How are you sending emails?

Comment: The system is developed by our teams to manage user form. So when user create new form, we as developer will get a do-not-reply email as notification. We want to track those email using SendGrid but not sure how to setup it.

Comment: So you want to be able to receive that email with SendGrid and process it somehow?

Comment: Yes, just to record the email activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive emails with SendGrid you need to do a few things. Here's an overview of what you'll need to do:

1. Get a domain that you want to receive emails on.
2. Set up MX records for a hostname on that domain to receive emails via SendGrid. Note that the hostname you choose (it can be a subdomain) should be used exclusively to parse your incoming email. The MX record should point to `mx.sendgrid.net` with a priority of 10.
3. Set up the webhook URL. In your SendGrid dashboard, click *settings*, then *Inbound Parse* and then *Add Host & URL*
4. Specify the receiving domain or hostname and a URL that will receive the webhooks when an email is received.
5. Save

The process of [setting up the Inbound Parse Webhook is documented in detail here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook).

What you do with the webhook from then is up to you.

Comment: Do we need to authenticate that domain in order to be able to receive the email?

Comment: No, receiving email is a different process to sending it. And being able to set MX records for the domain definitely shows your ownership of it.